# Looping Based on 2 Value Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have 2 variable

ex :

```
compt = 9
first = 3
second = 2
```

then i want to looping based on compnt length and then change status on or off based on variable first and second

Output that i want :

```
On
On
On
Off
Off
On
On
On
Off
```

my current code is:

```
x,y=0,0
for i in range(0,compt):
   if x != first:
      print("On")
      x+=1
   elif x == first and y != second:
      print("Off")
```

but the output from code above is

```
On
On
On
Off
Off
On
On
On
On
```

can someone help me to solve my problem , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
compt = 9
first = 3
second = 2

for i in range(compt):
    max_val = first + second
    if i % max_val < first:
        print("on")
    else:
        print("off")
```

Output:

```
on
on
on
off
off
on
on
on
off
```

Comment: I need to study modulo more.. Cool solution.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from itertools import cycle, islice

total = 9

first = 3
second = 2

sequence = ["On" for _ in range(first)] + ["Off" for _ in range(second)]
print(sequence)

result = islice(cycle(sequence), 0, total)

for state in result:
    print(state)
```

output :

```
['On', 'On', 'On', 'Off', 'Off']
On
On
On
Off
Off
On
On
On
Off
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variation with `itertools`:

```
from itertools import cycle, repeat, chain

compt = 9
first = 3
second = 2

on = repeat("On", first)    # ["On", "On", ..] 
off = repeat("Off", second) # ["Off", "Off", ..]

for status in cycle(chain(on, off)): # combine on and off and repeat
    print(status)

    # break when compt is exhausted
    compt -= 1
    
    if compt <= 0:
        break
```

Comment: I like this answer. Maybe `islice(cycle(chain(on, off)), compt)` could work if you want to go `itertools` all the way. Also, consider adding some comments.

Comment: Thank you! That's a good point with `islice`, I didn't think about that but saw @Lenormju use it in his answer, it would make it even more concise. Comments incoming..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%`. We have a total `first + second` possibility. If our `i` is less than `first` it means that we are looking for `on` and if it's more than first we want to print `off`:

```
compt = 9
first = 3
second = 2
for i in range(compt):
    if i % (first + second) < first:
        print("ON")
    else:
        print("OFF")
```

Answer (score 0):

try it...

```
compt = 9
first = 3
second = 2
i=0
while i < compt:
    for k in range(0,first):
        i += 1
        print('on')
        if i >= compt:
            break
    for j in range(0,second):
        i += 1
        print('off')
        if i >= compt:
            break
```